# How to sign data served by API

Tags: ssl, certificate, digital-signature

I'm serving data through a private API and I want to sign them. My user are a bit paranoid and are keeping data on their own. They want to be sure the data they saved has came from me and have not been modified by anyone since. I cannot use only https because Https just prove the identity of the server. That's not enough they want to be sure data have not change, even me should not be able to change them.

Here is what I want to do.

1. Build a checksum of a data chunck using sha1 or else.
2. Build a digital signature of this checksum usign a private self-sign certificate.
3. serve through https the checksum, its signature, and my public key.

My questions are :

- Is it the right way to do it ?
- Should I buy a certificate for an authority like Comodo or Symantec ?
- Can I sign my checksum using my https certificate ?
- If I buy a certificate from an authority what happened when it expires ? Are my old checksum signature not valid anymore ?

Comment: How does "you signing the message with your private key" protect the data from being modified by you?

Comment: It is only working because they store a copy of the data and the checksum. If we cannot trust each other we will need a more drastic solution like blockchain. You can also invole a thrid part, and only allow him to sign the data. thus I wont be able to produce anymore signed data without his consent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Build a checksum of a data chunck using sha1 or else.
> 2. Build a digital signature of this checksum usign a private self-sign certificate.

You should do the digital signature on the message, not on a checksum (the digital signature process involves itself a hash of the message, but you do not have to take care of this)

You need a private key and a certificate. You could build your own self-signed certificate or request one to a Certification Authority (CA).

> 3. serve through https the checksum, its signature, and my public key.

You need to send the signature, not the checksum. Really https would not be needed to send the signature(but recommended) because the digital signature protects the content of the message and identifies the signer

The client should include the root certificate of your signing certificate in his trust store in order to be able to verify the signature. You can provide it offline or serve it by https.

> Should I buy a certificate for an authority like Comodo or Symantec ?

The client must trust your root certificate including it in his trustore (as said above). The advantage of a trusted CA is that usually the root certificate it is present by default in the client trustore and you do not need to import it.  But if you generate a self-signed certificate and you provide the public part to client, he can import it manually.

> Can I sign my checksum using my https certificate ?

No, https certificates must be used for SSL connections and has a specific key usage. Depending on the software used by your client, could reject the signature

> If I buy a certificate from an authority what happened when it expires ? Are my old checksum signature not valid anymore ?

A verification of a digital signature performed *after* expiration date of the certificate will fail by default. If your client wants to do this, then the client or you have to protect the signature with a time stamp (issued by a third party Time Stamp Authority). When the certificate of the time stamp is close to expire, it is possible to add other timestamp